# Passing an argument from a regular class to an activity

Tags: android

I would like to call a method in an activity and pass an argument to it from a non activity regular class in android. 
As i understand, i cant simple use the following code, plus it does not work:

```
int mySound = 0;
SoundsActivity soundsActivity = new SoundsActivity();
soundsActivity.playSound(mySound);
```

That code is located in a regular class called "MyAdapter".

Comment: Activity is a LifeCycle owner. Which basically means at any point it could be `paused`, `stopped` or even `destroyed` hence it is ill adviced to store instances of it and call methods on them. 
Judging from your code I believe you would need to look into `Intent`.  Please elaborate on what you're trying to do with this.

Comment: I have this class called "MyAdapter". That class is in charge of gathering the data that is used to make a grid layout of multiple "cubes" , each one with a different text and sound. I have a method in that class that receives a certain ID that I need to pass on to my Soundsactivity in order to play the corresponding sound in the activity. So I am trying to call on a method that is in SoundActivity and pass an int  (ID) to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. I can't be specific since you didn't really show any code.

You can't do what you're trying to do though. Activities can't be instantiated like that (as well as anything extending Context), and it won't do what you want.

1. Use a broadcast.

   This will require that you have a Context object passed into your Adapter, which you can do simply by modifying the constructor and adding a global variable:

   ```
   private Context context;

   public MyAdapter(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }
   ```

   Then you can use that Context to send a local broadcast with your own action:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent("my_custom_action");
   intent.putExtra("sound_type", 0);
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```

   And receive that action in your Activity to call your method: [See Context-registered Receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

   When you construct the Adapter, pass a Context object into it. If you're constructing from an Activity (hopefully SoundsActivity), use `this`:

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
   ```
2. Use a callback.

   Delcare an interface somewhere:

   ```
   public interface AdapterCallback {
       void onRequestPlaySound(int type);
   }
   ```

   Implement that interface in your Activity:

   ```
   public class SoundsActivity extends Activity implements AdapterCallback {
       //...

       @Override
       public void onRequestPlaySound(int type) {
           playSound(type);
       }

       //...
   }
   ```

   Add the interface as a parameter in your Adapter's constructor:

   ```
   private AdapterCallback callback;

   public MyAdapter(AdapterCallback callback) {
       this.callback = callback;
   }
   ```

   And then use `callback.onRequestPlaySound(0);` from wherever you need.

   When you construct the Adapter, pass your SoundsActivity instance into it. This will only work if you're constructing the Adapter from SoundsActivity:

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
   ```
3. Pass SoundsActivity directly.

   This isn't the cleanest way, nor is it the recommended way, but it will work. In your Adapter:

   ```
   private SoundsActivity activity;

   public MyAdapter(SoundsActivity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
   }
   ```

   And from SoundsActivity:

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
   ```

   Then just call `activity.playSound(0);` where you need to.

Comment: i used the number 2 option and it worked. Thanks so much!!